# Report Viewer showing same report when clicked two diff reports while both report's url is diff

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using report viewer in my project MVC3 asp.net to show report. there are 5 reports which are calling at run time with few parameters. When clicked on the single report and wait, so report is viewing perfectly but when i clicked on two reports with in 2 sec so both reports opened but both are same reports while clicked on two diff reports and both reports link also diff.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
public ActionResult ReportsViewer()
       {            
        ReportViewer rptViewer = new ReportViewer();
        rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        rptViewer.SizeToReportContent = false;
        rptViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        rptViewer.EnableViewState = true;
        rptViewer.AsyncRendering = false;
        rptViewer.ServerReport.Timeout = 1800000;
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl=reportsDetail.ReportServer;
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath =reportsDetail.ReportPath;
        rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(finalParam);
        rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
        return View("~/ReportView.cshtml", rptViewer);
    }
```

## ReportView.chtml Page

```
    @using ReportViewerForMvc;
    @model Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "ReportView";
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>  
    </head>
    <body>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
     @Html.ReportViewer(Model as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer);           
     }
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: How does reportsDetail get its values?

Comment: its an object that contains the info of report server.

Comment: You might be experiencing client session issues if you are rendering new reports in a new tab/window. When you navigate back to the old window and refresh the old report becomes the new report, something like that.

Comment: Yes, Ross Bush.